# C#: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net

I get the following error:

> Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object

This is my C Sharp code:

```
      DataTable tableAcces = dsAcces.Tables["dsPrinterAcces"];
      DataTable tableMDF = dsAcces.Tables["dsPrinterMDF"];
      DataRow newrow = null;


      foreach(DataRow dr in tableAcces.Rows)
       {
           newrow = tableMDF.NewRow();

        newrow["PRINTER_ID"] = dr["PRINTER_ID"];
        newrow["MERK"] = dr["MERK"];
        newrow["MODEL"] = dr["MODEL"];
        newrow["LOKAAL_ID"] = dr["LOKAAL_ID"];

        tableMDF.Rows.Add(newrow);
      }

      daMDF.Update(dsMDF, "dsPrinterMDF");
      lblSucces.Text = "Gelukt. De tabel printers is overgezet.";
    }
```

In this line, he throws the error:

```
newrow = tableMDF.NewRow();
```

Thanks a lot,

Vincent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tableMDF` is null then.  You need to find out why `dsAcces.Tables["dsPrinterMDF"]` is returning null at the top.

Comment: It is an empty table, maybe is that the problem?

Comment: It's possible, but I would have expected the set to contain the table object with zero rows.  Are you sure you have the table name correct?

Comment: I have found the error. It was a typo.

This: DataTable tableMDF = dsAcces.Tables["dsPrinterMDF"]; --> DataTable tableMDF = dsMDF.Tables["dsPrinterMDF"];

Answer (score 0):

It seems that dsAcces.Tables["dsPrinterMDF"] returns null and not a table. Maybe this table is not found or you have a typo in it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `tableMDF` is null, check if there is a table `dsPrinterMDF`.

Answer (score 0):

```
dsAcces.Tables["dsPrinterMDF"]
```

is seemingly null, so make sure this delivers a DataTable. I'd guess that the identifier `dsPrinterMDF` doesn't exist (e.g. has a different capitalization)

Answer (score 0):

Here is all my code:

```
  ng connStringAcces = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RandAppAcces"].ToString();
  connAcces = new OleDbConnection(connStringAcces);


  daAcces = new OleDbDataAdapter();


  string sqlSelectAcces = "SELECT * FROM tblPrinter";
  OleDbCommand cmdAcces = new OleDbCommand(sqlSelectAcces, connAcces);
  daAcces.SelectCommand = cmdAcces;

  string connStringMDF = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RandAppMDF"].ToString();
  connMDF = new SqlConnection(connStringMDF);

  daMDF = new SqlDataAdapter();

  string sqlSelectMDF = "SELECT * FROM tblPrinter";
  SqlCommand cmdMDF = new SqlCommand(sqlSelectMDF, connMDF);
  daMDF.SelectCommand = cmdMDF;

  string sqlInsertMDF = @"INSERT INTO tblPrinter(PRINTER_ID, MERK, MODEL, LOKAAL_ID)" +
    @"VALUES (@PRINTER_ID, @MERK, @MODEL, @LOKAAL_ID)";

  cmdMDF = new SqlCommand(sqlInsertMDF, connMDF);

  cmdMDF.Parameters.Add("@PRINTER_ID", SqlDbType.Int, 0, "PRINTER_ID");
  cmdMDF.Parameters.Add("@MERK", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100, "MERK");
  cmdMDF.Parameters.Add("@MODEL", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100, "MODEL");
  cmdMDF.Parameters.Add("@LOKAAL_ID", SqlDbType.Int, 0, "LOKAAL_ID");

   daMDF.InsertCommand = cmdMDF;

  dsMDF = new DataSet();
  dsAcces = new DataSet();

  daMDF.Fill(dsMDF, "dsPrinterMDF");
  daAcces.Fill(dsAcces, "dsPrinterAcces");

  DataTable tableAcces = dsAcces.Tables["dsPrinterAcces"];
  DataTable tableMDF = dsAcces.Tables["dsPrinterMDF"];
  DataRow newrow = null;


  foreach(DataRow dr in tableAcces.Rows)
   {
       newrow = tableMDF.NewRow();

    newrow["PRINTER_ID"] = dr["PRINTER_ID"];
    newrow["MERK"] = dr["MERK"];
    newrow["MODEL"] = dr["MODEL"];
    newrow["LOKAAL_ID"] = dr["LOKAAL_ID"];

    tableMDF.Rows.Add(newrow);
  }
```

Comment: @Vinzcent - for future reference, this is not a conventional forum - you can edit your question (and your answers) so what you need to do is put the above into the original question.